# Device Driver programming - USB

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, usb-hostcontroller

I have to discuss the codeflow of the USB host controller. This USB host controller is the interface between the device and the OS. There are numerous USB devices (eg.keyboard,camera,mouse,etc).

Where will I find the code to see how the communication between the USB device and OS happens through the USB host-controller ?

Answer (score 1):

Download the Linux kernel source code, and start reading the code in `drivers/usb`. [Here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/) an online reference, and the [README](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/README) about the USB-tree

Comment: I need to find the open,read and write entry points of the usb. there are so many folders . which one to choose.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look at USB host controller specifications - UHCI/OHCI/EHCI/XHCI because this knowledge will be necessary to understand whole USB stack in linux kernel.

You may also download some example sources provided by several embedded microcontroller producers (i.e. Atmel). Probably those drivers will be easier to analyse than linux sources.